# is it possible to ignore assembly manifest mismatch?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a couple of libraries in my asp.net website that I pulled in using NuGet.

Problem is I am getting this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK, Version=1.5.9.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd2d24cd2bace800' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

One of the libraries I am trying to use needs to use the AWSSDK but apparently it is looking for an older version I can no longer get.

Is it possible to ignore this error?

This is a brand new website with no code in it yet, just what has been pulled in by NuGet, the web.config is empty.

### EDIT:

I added Fusion logging and now I get:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = WIN-FSSH1EIG4NE\Max
LOG: DisplayName = AWSSDK, Version=1.5.9.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd2d24cd2bace800
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Max/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/WebSites/images.RepZio/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\images.RepZio\bin
Calling assembly : ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader, Version=3.3.2.447, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\images\web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: AWSSDK, Version=1.5.9.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd2d24cd2bace800
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Max/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/8dcd52e9/53da58e/AWSSDK.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Max/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/8dcd52e9/53da58e/AWSSDK/AWSSDK.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Max/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/WebSites/images/bin/AWSSDK.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I get the same error if I add a bindingRedirect as mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: Look at `bindingRedirect` in the web.config.

Comment: same error happens, I enabled logging and now I get the above under EDIT

Comment: Show the entry you made in the web.config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latest (1.5.13.0) AWSSDK release seems to have been signed with a different key than the previous releases. So unfortunately a bindingRedirect won't work.

Proceed as follows:

Open the package manager console (Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console) and type:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package -Force AWSSDK
```

followed by:

```
PM> Install-Package AWSSDK -Version 1.5.12.1
```

Then double check your web.config file. Make sure that it only contains the following binding redirect for AWSSDK:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="AWSSDK" publicKeyToken="cd2d24cd2bace800" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.12.1" newVersion="1.5.12.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Now, your project should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit .csproj file and remove the Version=1.5.9.1 from line where the assembly awssdk is referenced.